# Codesigning a Windows build with electron-builder, on a Mac, not working

Tags: windows, electron, electron-builder

I am getting an issue code-signing a Windows .exe build, on a Mac, using a .p12 certificate generated by Apple, and stored in the Mac keychain.

My electron-builder version is: 20.28.1
And the target build i'm trying to run is a Windows ia32 build.

Codesigning works for the Mac app fine. But when trying to sign the Windows build it's not able to sign it.

If possible I would like to try and sign Windows build on a macOS machine, as I've read this is possible in the docs (I hope I've read that correctly?)

After trying to codesign I check the build using:

`codesign -dv [path/to/app/appname].exe`

And always get (for the Windows build only, the Mac app signs fine):

`code object is not signed at all`

I am building for both Mac and Windows, but for Windows I only build for the ia32 architecture at the moment. Here is what my build config looks like in my package.json

```
"build": {
    "appId": "[my-app-id]",
    "files": [
      "public/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "build/resources"
    },
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
      "target": [
        "dmg",
        "zip"
      ],
      "publish": {
        "provider": "s3",
        "bucket": "[BUCKET_NAME]",
        "path": "my-path"
      }
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "ia32"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "publish": {
        "provider": "s3",
        "bucket": "[BUCKET NAME]",
        "path": "my-path"
      }
    },
    "extends": null
  },
```

And here also is how my .env file looks, where I load up environment variables for electron-builder:

```
export ENV_NAME=staging

export CSC_NAME='[certificatename]' #example 1A3JKJD89O
export CSC_LINK=./path/to/mycert/cert.p12
export CSC_KEY_PASSWORD='my-passowrd'
export WIN_CSC_LINK=./path/to/mycert/cert.p12
export WIN_CSC_KEY_PASSWORD='my-passowrd'
export CSC_IDENTITY_AUTO_DISCOVERY=true
export DEBUG=electron-builder

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=[AWSKEYID]
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=[AWSSECRETACCESSKEY]
export AWS_S3_ENDPOINT=[S3ENDPOINT]
```

And finally, here's the yarn command I run to package the build (this is in a yarn script)

```
export $(grep -v '^#' ./path/t/my/env/file/staging.env | xargs) && electron-builder -p never -mw --ia32
```

I am not sure what I am missing here? Would anyone have an idea of what else I would need to do?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand you have to use compatible certificates:

https://www.electron.build/code-signing

> To sign an app on Windows, there are two types of certificates:
>
> EV Code Signing Certificate
>
> Code Signing Certificate

Personally getting the right certificate was hard. A certificate that will work for Windows is not easy to get, I had to go through a lot of paperwork to get this done.
I hope that this article, will make your life easier:
https://blog.dcpos.ch/how-to-make-your-electron-app-sexy

Go to the section: Signed Installers

Quoting the article:

> To get a Windows signing certificate, we recommend Digicert. The
> documentation for Windows app signing is surprisingly bad. If you go
> with the wrong vendor, they'll ask you to mail them notarized
> paperwork. That makes it a slow and annoying process to get the cert.
> Digicert is easier: they just send you a password via Certified Mail,
> you go to the post office, show your ID to pick it up, and bam, you
> get your signing certificate.

Comment: Thanks gba, I ended up getting a Standard certificate from DigiCert and this worked. Thanks!

Comment: @AntoniodePerio did you get any alert of "Unknown Editor" in windows after signed it?

Comment: @SergioQuintero no I didn't - For some other context I've moved away from signing and building Windows build on a Mac. I've ran into too many issues with the resulting .exe and it was much simpler to build Windows on Windows. This is probably the recommended route I would go with if you are looking at Electron windows builds at the moment. It's also the recommended solution from electron-builder

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having issues actually getting the cert to use on your Mac, here's what worked for me: (I ended up getting it via windows, it's just too messy getting the cert via Mac)

1. Use **IE 11 on Windows** to REQUEST the cert (it should generate it
   via your preferred cert profiders website automatically (I use Comodo as you don't need to wait for them to send a USB stick)
2. Once they issue you your cert, use the email link your cert providers sends you and open with the **same browser** that you requested it via. It should say “success”, but nothing else visually will happen.
3. Open IE settings, find certs in “content” and export as .PFX WITH private key. (you'll need to specify a password)
4. Copy the cert over to your Mac, and open in keychain.
5. Finally, you can now export it in **.p12 format** and save to your dir as specified in your app, and built/sign the app via your build command.

If anybody knows an easier way, please share!